# Stratio setup: connection refused error

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, mesos, mesosphere, stratio

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxLNC.png)

I am setting up stratio admin, but it can't get ports. every time I am getting connection refused error. If you have experience what can be the reason, I'll be waiting your answers.

I have made FQDN s for master and slave computers. 
master: reslab1.ibsu.edu.ge
slaves: reslab2.ibsu.edu.ge ,  reslab3.ibsu.edu.ge,  reslab4.ibsu.edu.ge

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.
I didn't have installed SSH server. There are some steps also after instalation of ssh server, you have to change /etc/ssh/ssd_config  file, add new ssh user.
If anybody have the same problem you can find out the reason here 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring

Comment: hi i am also getting the same error can you please explain the error